# Changing one independent variable in a regression analysis and keeping the dependent variable the same!

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I have a regression model which looks like this:
Y+1 = 0 + 1X1 + 2X2t + 3X3t + 4X4 + εt

Where I first run the model with X1 “as it is” and then I want to change the variable X1 to see what effect a potential another way of accounting might have.  Then I want to compare the differences in 1 and r-squared between the models. My question is then is it possible to compare 1 between the different regression models?
Regards,
Daniel

Comment: Not clear. What do you mean by "I want to change the variable X1 to see what effect a potential another way of accounting might have" ? If you mean, changing the  coding of (X1), then it does not make sense to directly compare (beta1) between the 2 models.